# SQL function returning result of select case

Tags: mysql, sql, function, triggers, case

I need to create a function that takes in parameter an id. Then I do a select case on a table where for this given id. The when statements in the case count the number of rows.

Here is my function:

```
CREATE function db_name.insert_stage(idStage INT)
    returns integer
    BEGIN   
        SELECT CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) < 10 THEN 0
            WHEN COUNT(*) >= 10 and COUNT(*) <= 12 THEN 392
            WHEN COUNT(*) >= 13 and COUNT(*) <= 17 THEN 490
            ELSE 588
            END AS cost
        FROM inscriptions WHERE paid = 1 AND id_stage = idStage;
        RETURN cost;
    END
```

Then I use a trigger to set the cost in a field for each row already existing in stage. This trigger will also be called on insert in stage:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_stage_frais_secretariat BEFORE INSERT ON stage
FOR EACH ROW SET stage.fraisSecretariat = select anper_extranet.insert_stage(stage.id);
```

I don't know if the trigger is working yet, because the function isn't.

Here is what phpmyadmin tells me:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

I have no idea what's wrong at line 10, because it feels to me it is the when, although I tried the select statement and it works.

Comment: In a MySQL trigger, you should almost always be referencing `new` and/or `old`. I don't see them in your trigger

Comment: Like this?: CREATE TRIGGER insert_stage_frais_secretariat BEFORE INSERT ON stage
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.fraisSecretariat = select anper_extranet.insert_stage(stage.id);  Thing is atm my function isn't working so i can't create the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION db_name.insert_stage(idStage INT)
RETURNS Integer
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_name INTEGER;
  SET var_name = 0;
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) < 10 THEN 0
    WHEN COUNT(*) >= 10 and COUNT(*) <= 12 THEN 392
    WHEN COUNT(*) >= 13 and COUNT(*) <= 17 THEN 490
    ELSE 588
    END
into var_name
FROM inscriptions WHERE paid = 1 AND id_stage = idStage;   
 RETURN var_name;
END //
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) < 10 THEN 0
        WHEN COUNT(*) >= 10 and CO' at line 4

Comment: You forgot the BEGIN btw

Comment: Your last edit is working, thx! Though I have now a problem with my trigger: CREATE TRIGGER insert_stage_cost BEFORE INSERT ON stage
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.cost = select db_name.insert_stage(stage.id);  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select db_name.insert_stage(stage.id)' at line 2  Is this about the stage.id not working?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER insert_stage_cost BEFORE INSERT ON stage FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.cost = select db_name.insert_stage(OLD.id);

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER insert_stage_cost BEFORE INSERT ON stage 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.cost = (SELECT db_name.insert_stage(NEW.id))

Comment: Syntax is now correct, the trigger is created. But when i want to use it: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'stage' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.